# How to override a parent class method in React?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reactjs

I'm extending a base class and overriding a method in the base class. But when I call it, it calls the super class version. How do I override the method?

```
    var Hello = React.createClass( {

        getName: function() { return "super" },

        render: function() {

            return <div>This is: {this.getName()}</div>;
        }
    });

    class HelloChild extends Hello {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);

          console.log( this.getName());
        }
        getName()
        {
          return "Child";
        }
    };
```

I want it to print "This is: Child" but it prints "This is: super"

Comment: https://jsbin.com/qizihe/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer (adapted from here: https://gist.github.com/Zodiase/af44115098b20d69c531 ) - the base class needs to also be defined in an ES6 manner:

```
class Hello extends React.Component {

        //abstract getName()
        getName()
        {
            if (new.target === Hello) {
                throw new TypeError("method not implemented");
            }
        }

        render() {

            return <div>This is: {this.getName()}</div>;
        }
    };
```

Comment: The OP wants to know how to access subclass from superclass (which is impossible AFAIK), not how to make an abstract method-the super and subclass methods have different implementations

Comment: That is the OP ^

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you're mixing ES6 type class declaration (ex. Hello) with old school Javascript declaration (ex. HelloChild).  To fix HelloChild, bind the method to the class.

```
class HelloChild extends Hello {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.getName = this.getName.bind(this); // This is important

      console.log( this.getName());
    }

    getName()
    {
      return "Child";
    }
};
```

Then it'll work.

Answer (score 3):

Actually you can override method to execute code from your subclass

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
getName() {
 super.getName();
 }
}


class HelloChild extends Hello {
getName()
    {
      return "Child";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that this answer proposes different approach:

I wonder why you should do this in the first place, my point is that directly coupling two react components is not a right way to implement re-usability in React.

If you are trying to have multiple child components which extends one parent, What I would do is, to have child components and a higher-order component and then implement common functionality with [Composition](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750#.o4pozs6lv). This way you can skip those methods, which you were trying to override and so everything would stay clear.