# Cannot Override A Method In React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, components

I have two components:

```
var A = React.createClass( {

   doSomething: function() { return "I am A" },

    render() {
    return(
        <h1>{this.doSomething()}</h1>
      );    
   }
    });

class B extends A {
   doSomething(): any {
     console.log("I am B");
   } 
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wp4wshdu/

I have the same problem as here => [How to override a parent class method in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38758518/how-to-override-a-parent-class-method-in-react) And it seems to be due to the fact that only component B defined in the EC-6 style. My problem is that I cannot change A class. How can I make React use the B's method in this case?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wp4wshdu/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to override a parent class method in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38758518/how-to-override-a-parent-class-method-in-react)

Comment: @Hitmands, it might be a bad example since it seems to work as expected in REPL... I just tried to explain the problem I am facing in my project and I might be missing something. I was just wondering if such behaviour possible in React that in some cases it uses the parent's methods instead of the component's?

Comment: @AngelCuenca, thank you. Indeed, I have the same problem just could explain it worse. It seems to be that the problem is that only the child component is defined in the ES6 style. I still have a question though what can I do in the situation when I cannot rewrite the parent's class and adjust it to the ES6-style

Comment: If it's not actually a class, please, provide real code for it.

Comment: Usually subclassing components in React isn't a good idea. If you need to tweak behavior you should be using a composition-based approach instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code above `doSomething` is instance method on A and prototype method in B.

It's roughly same as

```
 class A extends React.Component {
   doSomething = () => {
     console.log("I am A");
   } 
 }

 class B extends A {
   doSomething() { ... } 
 }
```

And `doSomething` from A beats `doSomething` from B in prototype chain. It's conventional to stick to prototype properties for methods in ES6 classes everywhere to avoid problems like this one. If this is not possible, `doSomething` should be made an instance method in child class, too:

```
 class B extends A {
   doSomething = () => { ... } 
 }
```

Comment: Sounds legit. However, I cannot make it work :( https://jsfiddle.net/ffgawww2/ Also not in my project with webpack.

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong with a fiddle and how to set it up properly, but class fields are [Stage 2 proposal](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-2/), and Babel should be configured with Stage 2 (or lower).