# Does ECMAScript 6 encourage the use of classical inheritance in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, ecmascript-6

I've come across many [proponents](http://aaditmshah.github.io/why-prototypal-inheritance-matters/) of true prototypical inheritance in JavaScript (as opposed to constructor inheritance). They suggest the `new` keyword shouldn't be used as it prevents the use of functional programming in the language.

Does ES6 encourage the use of classical inheritance? Considering the fact that it introduces the keyword `class` (called with the `new` keyword).

Comment: [Quoting MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) 

> JavaScript classes introduced in ECMAScript 2015 are primarily **syntactical sugar** over JavaScript's existing prototype-based inheritance. The class syntax is not introducing a new object-oriented inheritance model to JavaScript. JavaScript classes provide a much simpler and clearer syntax to create objects and deal with inheritance.

Comment: The problem of not being able to use `.apply()` with `new` is solved as of ECMAScript 6. You can now use spread syntax: `new Person(...args)`. Much has changed since that article. The complaint about it *looking like* classical inheritance is only relevant to those who don't understand that different languages have different semantics.

Comment: @spanky, could you elaborate on that? Write an answer :)

Comment: Why does `new` somehow "prevent" functional programming? Because the constructor function cannot just be passed as is? That's easy to solve: `(...args) => new Something(...args)`. The way I see it: Syntax is an interface. You can use it or you don't. You can use `while` loops all the way and ignore `for` loops completely. Same with the `class` syntax. Choose what you are comfortable with.

Comment: Hey there, I'm the author of that blog post you linked to. As spanky and Felix suggest, take that blog post with a grain of salt. I think I'll write a new blog post detailing my new views.

Comment: @AaditMShah, great to have you comment on this! Would you mind explaining your new views in an answer?

Comment: It's too long to fit into an answer. Hence, I'll write a blog post instead. However, in a sentence I'd say that my new view is to stay away from inheritance altogether and embrace [interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_(object-oriented_programming)) instead.

Comment: @LiroyLeshed: Not all situations fit into one paradigm. They all have pros and cons. Inheritance is great until it's not. Contract/interface based programming is great until it's not. Composition is great until it's not. The biggest problems arise when one jumps on a single bandwagon and tries to squeeze all their code into it. Be well-rounded and make informed decisions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article is outdated. The problem of not being able to use `.apply()` with `new` is solved as of ECMAScript 6. You can now use spread syntax: `new Person(...args)`.

The new `class` syntax *enhances* prototypal inheritance by providing better code organization, neater syntax and some capabilities that were previously not possible. Even though it uses the keyword `class`, it has nothing to do with classical inheritance as found in Java, C++, etc..

No matter what you decide to use, endeavor to write clear, understandable, maintainable code, and you'll do well.

Comment: Sheesh. I need to remove that blog post or write a new one. Seems to be confusing newcomers instead of helping them.

Answer (score 1):

There are many patterns to achieve inheritance in JS. ES6 classes are just  syntactic sugar for one of them.

ECMAScript 6 is still JavaScript and doesn't encourage any particular paradigm. However, there are practical considerations that are suggested by ES6 classes, which are idiomatic solution for inheritance in ES6.

When ES6 classes are inherited by non-ES6 classes, bad things may happen:

```
class Es6Class {}

function Es5Class() {
  var _this = Object.create(Es6Class.prototype);
  _this = Es6Class.apply(_this, arguments);
  return _this;
}
```

This is natural to call a constructor with `call` or `apply` and existing context on construction (this is roughly what happens when ES6 classes are transpiled with Babel or Typescript). But ES6 classes have built-in protection against calling them without `new`, so `Es5Class` will fail.

Another problem appears when ES5 classes that implement random inheritance recipe are inherited by ES6 classes (as shown in [this React question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45444435/3731501)):

```
function Es5ClassWithShallowPrototypeChain() {
  var _this = {};
  _this = AnotherEs5Class.call(_this, arguments);
  _this.method = function () {};
}

class Es6Class {
  method() {}
}
```

In code above it's expected that `Es6Class` will override `method` but this won't happen, because `method` is instance method (`this.method`) in `Es5ClassWithShallowPrototypeChain` and prototype method (`this.__proto__method`) in `Es6Class`.

A developer is free to choose any inheritance recipe he/she is comfortable but should always take into account how the recipe will affect third-party code. While ES6 class inheritance implementation is idiomatic to JS and generally can be used as a rule of thumb in ES6 code.

Comment: It's not totally clear from this if you're aware, but either way it's good to call out. You can extend ES6 with normal functions, but you need to use `var _this = Reflect.construct(Es6Class, arguments, new.target)`, which is only available on ES6 environments, then you can just put `method` on `Es5Class.prototype` the same way you do in ES5 normally.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Thanks for mentioning it, yes, it's possible to replace `Es6Class.apply` with it, and also Reflect.construct should be polyfillable. These examples primarily apply to cases when one of those classes is supplied by or to third-party code, thus a dev is unaware of the problem before it appears (encountered it in person).

Answer (score 0):

I would say yes, it does. As far as I know, it is still prototypical inheritance under the hood; the class keyword formalizes a common design pattern. This article covers this:
[Better JavaScript with ES6, Pt. II: A Deep Dive into Classes](https://scotch.io/tutorials/better-javascript-with-es6-pt-ii-a-deep-dive-into-classes)

You can still do [functional programming in JavaScript](https://opensource.com/article/17/6/functional-javascript), but overall, the JS community seems to be moving away from that and more toward a classical object-oriented programming style.