# Extending base class property in Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux-form

I'm trying to create a wrapper class for ReactReduxForm's `Control` component to add additional functionality.  Here is the base class/component definition:

```
export class Control<T> extends React.Component<ControlProps<T>, {}> {
    static custom: React.ComponentClass<ControlProps<HTMLInputElement>>;
    static input: React.ComponentClass<ControlProps<HTMLInputElement>>;
    static text: React.ComponentClass<ControlProps<HTMLInputElement>>;
    static textarea: React.ComponentClass<ControlProps<HTMLTextAreaElement>>;
    static radio: React.ComponentClass<ControlProps<HTMLInputElement>>;
    static checkbox: React.ComponentClass<ControlProps<HTMLInputElement>>;
    static file: React.ComponentClass<ControlProps<HTMLInputElement>>;
    static select: React.ComponentClass<ControlProps<HTMLSelectElement>>;
    static reset: React.ComponentClass<ControlProps<HTMLButtonElement>>;
    static button: React.ComponentClass<ControlProps<HTMLButtonElement>>;
}
```

I would like to override `onKeyPress` functionality for all types of controls (eg. input, text, textarea, etc.) which are static properties of the base `Control` class/component.

Here is my skeleton definition for my derived class:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Control } from "react-redux-form";

export class CustomControl<T> extends Control<T> { }
```

I would like the following functionality to apply to all control types (eg. text, select, etc.) of `CustomControl`:

```
  onKeyPress(e: any) {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
```

How can I have my `onKeyPress() functionality be used?

Comment: you can check this anser https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38758518/how-to-override-a-parent-class-method-in-react

Answer (score 4):

Instead of extending `Control` with `CustomControl` you should wrap it.

What you are really looking to do is modify the `render()` method of `Control` and add in a custom `onKeyPress`. The problem with extending `Control` is that you can only **override** `Control`'s render method and not make changes to pieces of it.

However, if you **wrap** the `Control` component with your own component, you are able to influence it in the way you are looking to.

If you look at the definition for `ControlProps<T>` you will see this:

```
export interface ControlProps<T> extends React.HTMLProps<T> {
```

Because it is extending `React.HTMLProps` it supports the `onKeyPress` method as a prop.

If we combine all this information together, you can do something like:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Control, ControlProps } from "react-redux-form";

export class CustomControl<T> extends React.Component<ControlProps<T>> {

    onKeyPress(e: any) {
        if (e.key === "Enter") {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }

    render() {
        return <Control {...this.props} onKeyPress={e => this.onKeyPress(e)} />;
    }
}
```

Please note that the above implementation will completely override any `onKeyPress` passed as a prop to `CustomControl` in favor of your custom `onKeyPress`.

If you also wanted to call any `onKeyPress` that gets passed as a prop you could add the following to the bottom of your custom `onKeyPress` function:

```
// After custom logic call any onKeyPress passed to this
this.props.onKeyPress && this.props.onKeyPress(e);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I have pretty strict typescript settings in my tsconfig for this project and when I implement your code, I get the following error:  `Types of property 'ref' are incompatible.
            Types of parameters 'instance' and 'instance' are incompatible.
              Type 'Control<{}> | null' is not assignable to type 'T | null'.
                Type 'Control<{}>' is not assignable to type 'T | null'.
                  Type 'Control<{}>' is not assignable to type 'T'.'`

Comment: While I can't be entirely sure without seeing more of your code, are you doing `<CustomControl ref=...` anywhere and trying to use it's ref? If so, would you try changing that to the `getRef` prop that react-redux-form exposes in their [typings](https://github.com/davidkpiano/react-redux-form/blob/master/react-redux-form.d.ts)

Answer (score 0):

try overriding the base javascript function `onKeyPress()` with an EventListener which wait for event trigger:

```js
document.addEventListener('keypress', yourCallBack, true);

yourCallBack() {
  // your code
}
```

Put inside app.component.ts and should be fine

Comment: Wouldn't that fire on every keypress event and not just those fired by react-redux-form controls?  That would be undesirable, at the very least, for textareas.

Comment: I could easily throw a logic in there to only call `e.preventDefault()` if it's not a textarea, but there are inline inputs outside of RRF that I want enter to work for.  I need to only have this logic fired for these controls.

Comment: ok is more clear now. I think you could use a `element.addEventListener` instead of `document`, where Element is your RRF.